# Iterating through multiple large datasets in parallel

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am working on an application which needs to get source data from the sql server db using a stored procedure, do some calculation and store the results back to sql server using another stored procedure. The total source data is around 10.000.000 records which can be separated in 100 different datasets. So after I was able to do the complete process sequential using iterating a datareader (took over 50 hours) I am now looking for a solution to parallize the process so i could run 8 calculations at the same time(I am using server with 2 quadcore cpu's).
I tried examples with EF6, but ended up in problems since EF is not thread safe. Even a solution where every context was isolated did not work. by making use of

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities()) 
{ 
    var resGuid = ReserveGroupId(pIdForCalc, ctx);                            
    int pageNumber = 0;
    int pageSize = 200;
    bool DataNotComplete = true;
    while (DataNotComplete)
    {
        List<GetNextCalcDataSetPaged_Result> lstCalcDataSet = GetDataPaged    ((pIdForCalc,pageNumber,pageSize,ctx);
    if (lstCalcDataSet != null)
    {
    DataNotComplete = lstCalcDataSet.Count == pageSize;
        Parallel.ForEach(lstCalcDataSet, CalcDataRecord =>
        { if (ctx != null) CalcBundelSetParallel(CalcDataRecord, ctx); });
    }
pageNumber++;
}
```

Comment: It seems to me the performance issue isn't the fact that there is 10MM rows, there's something very heavy with what you're doing if it took 50 hours. I would start by optimizing that. Parallelization isn't really the answer when you can't hold large chunks of it in memory at once.

Comment: Retrieving the source data is the most time consuming issue, it takes around 3 seconds to get 200 records. For this reason I am trying to find the most efficient way to run the complete process :Retrieving source data, calculation and storing results in a parallel matter.

Comment: Consider going away from EF and just leveraging a `SqlDataReader`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I used a data reader in my first attempt which ran ok but when I try to open multiple readers to do multiple calculations simultaneous I ran into exceptions. I'll probably change my code to use separate connections for the readers.

Comment: Yeah, multiple readers will cause an issue. You won't even be able to do multiple readers with separate connections; you can't have multiple readers open at the same time because of how they are implemented.

Comment: I will add the data retrieve(using sqlDataReader), calc and update code in a separate assembly which I will start 8 times using a batch script or by creating a process from my starter app. Not the nicest solution but it works (already tried it in the beginning)

Answer (score 0):

One dirty way would be using disconnected DataSets filled with chunks of disconnected  data, by example, 200,000 records at time. Once in memory you can process it in parallel like this

```
//Setup empty dataset for results setting its schema
               dsResultSet.Tables.Add(ORM.GetDataSet("MyDataToProcess").Tables[0].Clone());

                object key = new object();

                //Iterate in parallel your Dataset
               Parallel.ForEach(ORM.GetDataSet("MyDataToProcess").Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), drow =>
                {
                    if (((string)drow["DataRecordKey"]).Contains(SomeKey))
                    {
                        //some process with the record
                        //...

                        lock (key)
                        {
                            //Add the result to other disconnected DataSet
                            dsResultSet.Tables[0].BeginLoadData();
                            dsResultSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(drow.ItemArray);
                            dsResultSet.Tables[0].EndLoadData();
                        }
                    }

                });`
```

I know, it is not pretty like the Entity Framework code, but this code worked for me reaching in milliseconds operations on 200,000 records in memory. The reason for the second table for results is that DataTables are not thread safe for update, just for read.